# Select which tensor to use in middle of TensorFlow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

### In Tensorflow, how would I go about selecting between a python list of Tensors in the middle of my graph as an input to the rest of the graph?

Basically, I have a python list of Tensors that are candidates to be used as inputs in the rest of the graph. I want to select from one of them without adding extra dependencies that require all of the Tensors in the list to be computed (I think that would happen if I used tf.cond). How can I select one of them? I can't do it at the python level because I choose the tensor based on a value computed from a placeholder. So for example:'

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(num_steps, None))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None,))
lengths = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None,))
# Pretend there is a bunch of lines of code here
output_index = max_sequence_length = tf.reduce_max(lengths)
final_output = potential_outputs[output_index] # won't work, output_index is Tensor
# Pretend the rest of the model uses final_output
```

### More info if you want it:

I am unrolling an RNN and I want to only unroll to the maximum length of the sequence. When this is less then the number of unrolling steps, there is a lot of wasted computation. Dynamic_rnn and static_rnn do not meet my needs, so I am trying to come up with my own custom method of unrolling the graph.

Answer (score 0):

To index in tensorflow use [tf.slice](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice).

It should be noted that based on the code you provided, I don't think you are indexing the outputs correctly using tf.reduce_max function since this is providing the actual maximum value across a given axis which may not be an integer (but I'm not sure how your network works). You may be looking for tf.argmax that returns to index for the maximum value. The issue with this however is that tensorflow does not a have a gradient defined for tf.argmax so that function cannot be a learned part of your network.

Comment: This doesnt answer my question unfortunately :( potential_outputs is a python list instead of a Tensor because I want to select from only one of the potential outputs without adding dependencies on the other potential outputs. As far as I know, having all the potential outputs packed into a Tensor would violate my need to only compute a single potential output of the list.